# ubuntu 12.04 - postfix - postmap missing

Tags: 12.04, package-management, email, postfix

I'm trying to change the default sender address on Postfix using the method described in [how to change default email address for postfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538817/how-to-change-default-email-address-for-postfix)

At some point we are required to run postmap, but the command is nowhere to be found and no package is providing it.
Has it been rendered obsolete? 
How are we suppose to generate db files than?

Answer (score 2):

`postmap` is included in the `postfix` package.

As you can see on [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/postfix/filelist) it's located in `/usr/sbin/postmap`.

If you can't run it you can try the following:

- Run `/usr/sbin/postmap` directly

  - If it's not there, try to reinstall `postfix`

    ```
    sudo apt-get --reinstall postfix
    ```
- Check if `/usr/sbin` is in your PATH (`/usr/sbin` will be highlighted using `grep`)

  ```
  echo $PATH | grep /usr/sbin
  ```

  - If it's not there, add it

    ```
    nano ~/.bashrc
    ```

    and add the following line (also run this in your terminal to apply this fix without a restart)

    ```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
    ```